# 03 kia spectra runs on fresh battery

Tags: electrical, battery, starting, kia, spectra

Car will fire up on good battery but after bout ten minutes lights go out acts hit nrake or anything and it dies hearing a buzzing from sensor or  throttle body  told needs alternator belt but seems tight starter at first acted like wasnt kicking out when try to start it even with fresh battery

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an alternator replacement. To check and see, after installing a fresh battery, take a voltage reading of the battery without the engine on. Start the car, then check the battery again, holding your multi-meter on the terminals to get a continuous reading. If the battery voltage is lower than where it started and continually drops, this means the alternator isn't putting out any voltage. Time for replacement. All of the symptoms you talk about are pretty indicative of a bad alternator.

If it's not showing any life, take it off and down to the parts store. They can check it for you to make sure that's what the issue is for sure. Most of the major parts stores here in the States have the ability to do this for you and will do it free of charge.